# Pass functions in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, lambda

Is it possible to pass a reference to a function to another function in F#?  Specifically, I'd like to pass lambda functions like

foo(fun x -> x ** 3)

More specifically, I need to know how I would refer to the passed function in a function that I wrote myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The [manual](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/manual/spec2.aspx#_Toc207785549) has this example:

```
> List.map (fun x -> x % 2 = 0) [1 .. 5];;

val it : bool list
= [false; true; false; true; false]
```

Answer (score 3):

Functions are first class citizens in F#. You can therefore pass them around just like you want to.

If you have a function like this:

```
let myFunction f =
    f 1 2 3
```

and **f** is function then the return value of **myFunction** is **f** applied to 1,2 and 3.

Comment: what if you want two functions as input to myFunction?

Answer (score 3):

Passing a lambda function to another function works like this:

Suppose we have a trivial function of our own as follows:

```
let functionThatTakesaFunctionAndAList f l = List.map f l
```

Now you can pass a lambda function and a list to it:

```
functionThatTakesaFunctionAndAList (fun x -> x ** 3.0) [1.0;2.0;3.0]
```

Inside our own function `functionThatTakesaFunctionAndAList` you can just refer to the lambda function as `f` because you called your first parameter `f`.

The result of the function call is of course:

```
float list = [1.0; 8.0; 27.0]
```